# linkedIn myApp sign in with linkedIn now show in my product list

Tags: linkedin-api

i created an app in my LinkedIn account and connect to a company and verified it.
but in the product i could not see the sign in with LinkedIn to access the "r-lite-profile" and "w-mail address" scope to post with 3 legs authentication.

i expected that see the sign in with LinkedIn in products in my app .

Comment: could you please provide some code?

Comment: i created an app with LinkedIn to access the LinkedIn API.i cant add scopes that i said above to my app.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.